# I don't have a CreatedTime column in tables. Is there any way to get the last row inserted time from SQL Server sys tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In one of the SQL Server database, tables don't have any `CreatedTime` or `Timestamp` columns exists.

I'm trying to get last row inserted time from all tables for some troubleshooting purposes.

Is there any way to get this from system tables or statistics? Thanks!

Comment: If you want it by table, you can try sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to see when the last user update was done.  There are some other places you can look but they might not even have any data for the table in question if there's not a recently active query or the query has been flushed from plan cache..

Comment: you can also trawl through fn_dblog function output to see if you can find anything, but it's a bit more involved/detailed. Some details here: https://blog.coeo.com/inside-the-transaction-log-file if log is truncated by backups etc then you might not get any info though